# Codeigniter CI_Form_validation undefined function

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

So I am getting the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::error_array() in /home/kmgpdev/public_html/projects/lm/application/controllers/api.php on line 64
```

Line 63 through 66 reads

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 0, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array()]));
    return false;
}
```

If I remove the 64th line it works fine, just no errors are produced.
Also here is my MY_Form_validation.php file I created as a custom library.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);

    }

    public function error_array()
    {
        if(count($this->_error_array > 0)) {
            return $this->_error_array;
        }
    }
}
```

So it running well in localhost, xampp and when I upload to my ubuntu server then it happend this error, I cannot figure out why this error is coming up. I'm using php 5.5, Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ye I custom it for my ajax working, just it's working well on localhost, but my ubuntu server not, tks your comment

Comment: I had similar problems before. Check the case of the file and the case of the class name.

Comment: thanks I've fixed, my issues due class name inside dicrectory, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the first error message, I have put a utility function like this directly under //system/libraries/Form_validation.php. Otherwise you can use $this->form_validation->error_string() instead of directly picking error array. In most cases, you would want your user to see the error as a string  :

```
function first_error_string($prefix = '', $suffix = '')
{
    // No errrors, validation passes!
    if (count($this->_error_array) === 0)
    {
        return '';
    }

    if ($prefix == '')
    {
        $prefix = $this->_error_prefix;
    }

    if ($suffix == '')
    {
        $suffix = $this->_error_suffix;
    }

    // Generate the error string
    $str = '';
    foreach ($this->_error_array as $val)
    {
        if ($val != '')
        {
            $str .= $prefix.$val.$suffix;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```